# Parallelize C++ Hardware Communication and Python Data Processing

Tags: python, c++, multiprocessing

I use the PICAM C++ API from princeton instruments to communicate with a EMCCD camera. I want to process the captured data in chunks during the measurement, as the CPU is mostly idle during image capture.

I tried using the multiprocessing module in python (which I use to process the image data after capturing all frames) like this:

```python
import multiprocessing

Q = multiprocessing.Queue()

process_camera = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_measurement, args=(), kwargs=experiment_settings)
process_camera.start()

process_data = multiprocessing.Process(target=sum_raw_data_to_matrix, args=(Q))
process_data = start()

process_camera.join()
process_data.join()
```

The my_measurement process calls a C++ script to communicate with the EMCCD camera and handles the capturing. After it finishes a certain amount of frames, it hands the created .raw file to the sum_raw_data_to_matrix process, which should start summing up all the captured frames in parallel to the next chunk of frames being captured on the camera.

Unfortunately, the process of capturing stalls at the moment of the ctypes call to start the C++ script and waits for the sum_raw_data_to_matrix process to fully finish, before continuing.

Is the ctypes module to execute C++ functions from within python not compatible with the multiprocessing module?

Comment: Your code isn't compatible with multiprocessing. Every example shows your code must be within `if __name__ == '__main__':` See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm aware of that and the main script that I execute to start everything runs the mentioned code snippet with if __name__ == '__main__':

Comment: So please click [edit] and update your code to be properly representative.